# Threaded Java Message Board Server

Tags: java, multithreading, serversocket

I've become stuck on a threaded message board server I'm trying to implement. I've set up the connections and started the thread, but now I'm stuck on how to set do anything with that, my message board is set up as a doubly linked list of topics, which themselves are made up of a linked list of messages.
This http://pastebin.com/uhcyxg2t is my server class, while this http://pastebin.com/taq5pV61 is my thread handler class.
I'm stuck at listAllTopics(), which is supposed to list titles of all topics on the message board, I'm not sure how to get the information from my topic list object to my thread so that it can be sent to the client.
My only idea so far has been to pass the topic list as a parameter of the thread, but I'm not sure if this would keep the topic list the same across all threads if it where added to or changed.
Any help you could give me would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8cH3iphm is the sorted topic list.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to do `public class SortedTopicList extends List<Topic>`. java.util.List is an interface, not a class...

Comment: It's my own implementation of List.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> topicNames = new ArrayList<>();

for(Topic t : threadServerTopicList)
    topicNames.add(t.getTitle());
```

Something like that. Give us the topic list class code.

Answer (score 0):

Its ok to share the list and it will reflect any change no matter what thread do the change, but SortedTopicList is not thread-safe at all and it must be. The problem of not being thread-safe is not the changes are seen or not by the other threads but that the threads may corrupt the structure while editing the list at the same time, or a thread might loop through a list being edited and might end up in an infinite loop or something.

You have to set mutual exclusion regions (mutex, synchronized keyword) so several threads don't access the list at the same time or forget about using hand-made data structures and use ones that supports concurrent operations. [This package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) might help you.